# Shrine - cannot read an attachment a second time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, shrine

After migrating from Carrierwave to Shrine, some of the tests started to failed. I've noticed that when calling `#read` from the column where the Shrine uploader is mounted, it can only by called once. By doing a second `#read` will return an empty string. Maybe I'm missing some configuration but the same code works for Carrierwave (I know it is a different uploader but for what I'm experiencing migrating to Shrine needs very few/almost none changes to the codebase)

```rb
# shrine.rb -> for testing
require "shrine"
require "shrine/storage/s3"
require "shrine/storage/file_system"

Shrine.plugin :activerecord
Shrine.plugin :cached_attachment_data
Shrine.plugin :determine_mime_type, analyzer: :mime_types

Shrine.storages = {
    cache: Shrine::Storage::FileSystem.new(
      "public",
      prefix: "tmp/cache",
    ),
    store: Shrine::Storage::FileSystem.new(
      "public",
      prefix: "tmp",
    ),
  }
```

```rb
# carrierwave.rb -> for testing

...

config.storage = :file
config.enable_processing = false
```

Comment: Where do you call `read`? Can you please also add the spec file or at least the relevant parts of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you can read the content agian, you have to reset the "read pointer".
You can do this by calling `.rewind`.

> Shrine is able to upload any IO-like object that implement methods #read, #rewind, #eof? and #close whose behaviour matches the IO class.

For Details see the [getting_started](https://github.com/shrinerb/shrine/blob/a5ad5ac5f29c5c434ebdf6b934ade9afabcb0449/doc/getting_started.md#io-abstraction) and [this examle](https://github.com/shrinerb/shrine/blob/ad270b8bb133c0f65c1d890d147f3b5ffa41e568/doc/retrieving_uploads.md#io-like-interface).

Comment: @jpac did you find this answer helpful? If so, please mark it as accepted.
Please let me know, if you miss something or anything is unclear.

Comment: your solution worked. I've also changed the code to use the `#open` before doing a read and ensure the file is closed at the end.